# load a datatable to an existing table in dataset

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

how can in load a `DataTable` to an existing table in my `DataSet`. something like this:

```
DataTable my_table = new DataTable("sale_info");
**add some row to my_table **
myDataSet.Tables.Add(my_table);
```

i have a table named `sale_info` in myDataset too and `myDataSet.Tables.Add(my_table);` is trying to add new one. actually i want update my table with new data from another table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `myDataSet.Tables["sale_info"].Merge(my_table)`.

However, you should simply add the rows directly to the existing table rather than creating a new table.